# Having sql error whenever i submit my form

Tags: mysql, sql, servlets

I am trying to grab the data from mySQL database and store into my arrayList. However, whenever i run this set of code, i got this error

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'displayname LIKE '%A%'' at line 1

However, I am not using any keyword, I included single quote for the wild card operator. Where have I done wrong or left out in the sql statement?

```
String sql = "SELECT * FROM azq.registration WHERE userId NOT IN (SELECT friendId FROM azq.friendlist WHERE userId ="
                        + session.getAttribute("userId")
                        + ") AND userId !="
                        + session.getAttribute("userId")
                        + "AND displayname LIKE '%" + searchText + "%'";
                // create the java statement
                Statement st = conn.createStatement();

                // execute the query, and get a java resultset
                ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(sql);

                // iterate through the java resultset
                while (rs.next()) {
                    Friends newList = new Friends();
                    newList.setFirstName(rs.getString("firstName"));
                    newList.setLastName(rs.getString("lastName"));
                    newList.setUserId(rs.getString("userId"));
                    newList.setDisplayname(rs.getString("displayname"));

                    resultList.add(newList);
                }
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Comment: Add a space before the 2nd AND and convert this to a paramaterized query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add a blank before `AND`:

```
                + session.getAttribute("userId")
                    + " AND displayname LIKE '%" + searchText + "%'";
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot a space:

```
                    + ") AND userId !="
                    + session.getAttribute("userId")
                    + "AND displayname LIKE '%" + searchText + "%'";
                       ^---here
```

so you're generating

```
... userID != fooAND displayname
```

If you'd look at the `sql` you generated, you'd have seen this.